# I want to access struct block default ID in its template

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I want to save stream field ID into it's template.

In short, in text_question.html I am giving id = {{ self.id }} but that return Nothing.

I want this because in question.html file I want it to compare with {{ 
field.id }} which return stream field ID

In another word, I want to store {{ field.id }}'s value in id field of text_question.html

models.py

```
class TextQuestionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    """Text Question"""

    question = blocks.CharBlock(required=True, help_text="Add your Question")
    is_save = blocks.BooleanBlock(label="Want to save this field ?", required=False)
    is_email = blocks.BooleanBlock(label="Want to get this field as an email ?", required=False)

    class Meta:  # noqa
        template = "question/question_field/text_question.html"
        icon = "edit"
        label = "Text Question"


@register_setting(icon='fa-commenting')
class QuestionSettings(BaseSetting):
    body = StreamField([
        ("text_question", TextQuestionBlock()),
    ], verbose_name='Question', blank=True)

    panels = [
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Question'
        verbose_name = 'Questions'
```

text_question.html

```
{% load tag_library %}
<input issave="{{self.is_save}}" isemail="{{ self.is_email }}" class="text_question" type="text" name="{{ self.question|to_name }}" id="{{ self.id }}" data-conv-question="{{ self.question }}"
```

question.html

```
<form name="question_form" action="" method="post" class="hidden">
            <div id="unique_id"></div>
                {% for field in question.body %}
                    {{ field.id }}
                {% endfor %}
            <input type="text" data-conv-question="test">
        </form>
```

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is not a built-in property of the block value - rather, it's a mechanism used by the StreamField container to keep track of its contents. It's not always meaningful for a block value to have an ID property: for example, the value of a CharBlock is a string, and you can't really have an `.id` property on a string. Similarly, child blocks of StructBlock won't be given one.

As a result, the id is not automatically available on a block's template - if you want it, you need to pass it explicitly from the calling template, via the `{% include_block %}` template tag. For example:

```
{% for field in question.body %}
    {% if field.block_type == 'text_question' %}
        {% include_block field with block_id=field.id %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will make the ID available on `text_question.html` as the variable `block_id`.